# Modify collection while looping through it

Tags: typescript, collections

I have a collection of objects in TypeScript.  Each object has a method called `getSubObjects` which returns a collection of objects of the same type containing the same method `getSubObjects`.  My requirement is

1. Have to iterate through the original collection calling `getSubObjects` of each object in the collection.
2. For each object returned call `getSubObjects` again.
3. Keep on going for each object returned until there is no object

So in my loop I want to do something like the following

```
objCol.forEach(item => {
  const col = item.getSubObjects();
  if(col){
      objCol.pushRange(col)
  }
});
```

I don't think this is possible in TypeScript, the only alternative I can think of is to resort to recursion, but I would rather avoid it if there an alternative way in which I can do this.

Comment: recursion is your friend here. However there are plenty of libraries that offer flatten utilities. ramda and lodash to name two.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid recursion by using a naive loop like the following (I did not run the [pseudo] code myself though):

First add another boolean property `processed` to each object, initialized `false`.
Then:

```
const processedAll = () => !objCol.some(o => !o.processed);

while (!processedAll()) {
    const extension = [];
    objCol.forEach(item => {
        if (!item.isProcessed) {
            item.processed = true;
            const col = item.getSubObjects();
            if (col) {
                col.processed = false;
                extension.pushRange(col)
            }
        }
    });
    objCol = [...objCol, extension];
}
```

Comment: can't I do this in a simple while loop, I tried a while loop and tried to modify it, but it did not step into the loop, it seems to cache the result

Comment: Did you try my suggested code? On each while loop iteration, `objCol` did not contain the additional pushed items?

Comment: yup, this does not work, in the `forEach` you are push an item into it, this makes the program stuck.